# Online training RNN (LSTM) with Tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow

I have developed a basic LSTM model which predict energy consumption for t+1, now I have been looking how to deploy and retrain my model :

How can I retrain my model continuously with recent data, I work in a iot environement and ideally I need to refit my model for each coming new point, any thoughts how it's done with tensorflow ?